# how can i fire button action event without any user action iphone xcode?

Tags: iphone

how can i fire button action event without any user action?

pls give me any sample..

Answer (score 3):

UIButtons are subclass of UIControl.  They use the [sendActionsForControlEvents:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendActionsForControlEvents:) method to send out events.  You can call that method on the button (or control) to have the actions sent.

```
[theButton  sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 0):

If user dont want to fire action on button,why do you show button,without showing button,u can do action.I think u need dynamic code (without interface builder),the code is

```
 [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(action1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 -(void) action1:(id)sender;
```

{
 }
hope this will help....

Comment: i think u may use NSNotification